# Objective C/iOS: Handling a selector call when a row is selected in a tableView.

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface

I have a tableViewController with a bunch of different options and I'm trying to add a selector call when one of those rows is selected.

The way I have it setup right now is that my TableViewController's child class has a subclass inside it that has a field 'selector' and I've been messing around with trying to invoke the selector there. However, this doesn't give me access to the object that actually implements the method the selector represents.

What is the right way to add a selector to an object? This object isn't going to be a button, and in the end the selector needs to be triggered on a didSelectRowAtIndexPath: call.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by subclassing the cells, adding a delegate and selector property. Which I then again accessed in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. I realize that this might not be best practise though, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good design for this problem would be to enumerate ALL the selectors you would be interested in calling (this of course is a finite number of selectors, as they are all required to exist explicitly), add this as a property to the cells (this would mean that you need to subclass UITableViewCell, of course) and write a switch-case in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method.